# Can I use React-Select Async (AsyncSelect) from a CDN? (I'm getting Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

As per the project manager's request, I can't bundle this with **npm**, so I'm stuck to using CDN versions of every library.
Everything is working well so far, React, Material-UI, React-Select and Babel.

But trying to include Async.js (*https://unpkg.com/react-select/lib/Async.js*) gives me `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

I see that in https://unpkg.com/react-select/dist/react-select.js there are references to `Async` & `AsyncSelect` but I can't figure out how to use the  AsyncSelect component as shown in https://react-select.com/async

This is how I'm using the libraries:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-select@2.1.2/dist/react-select.js"></script>
<!-- ... and other dependencies -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927307/how-to-import-from-react-select-cdn-with-react-and-babel) and copy / paste all the dependencies in this answer, you will be able to access `react-select` elements.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emotion@9.2.12/dist/emotion.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.5.10/prop-types.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-input-autosize@2.2.1/dist/react-input-autosize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-select@2.1.2/dist/react-select.min.js"></script>
```

Once that done `Async` specific component will be reachable via `Select.Async` like the following example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emotion@9.2.12/dist/emotion.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.5.10/prop-types.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-input-autosize@2.2.1/dist/react-input-autosize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-select@2.1.2/dist/react-select.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
 <div id="root"></div>
      <script type="text/babel">


      const options = [
        { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
        { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
        { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
      ];

      class App extends React.Component {
        state = {
          selectedOption: null,
        }
        handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
          this.setState({ selectedOption });
          console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
        }
        render() {
          const { selectedOption } = this.state;

          return (
            <div>
            Test Text
            <Select.Async
              value={selectedOption}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              options={options}
            />
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#root"))
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, merci beaucoup, Laura, I'm testing this to mark it as resolved.

Comment: Update: Working perfectly. Thanks!