# Is it possible to use react-select in the browser from the cdn?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, commonjs, es6-modules

Is it possible to use react-select directly from the browser without
bundlers nowadays?

The most recent version that I found to be able to do so was 2.1.2:
[How to import from React-Select CDN with React and Babel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927307/how-to-import-from-react-select-cdn-with-react-and-babel)

They used to provide `react-select.min.js` in the umd format back then.

Nowadays they have `react-select.browser.esm.js` and `react-select.browser.cjs.js` (https://unpkg.com/browse/react-select@3.1.0/dist/), but I couldn't get any of those working from the browser.

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: @harrrrrrry I've switched to Svelte. Here's a nice [intro](https://medium.com/better-programming/react-vue-and-svelte-templates-side-by-side-4aa52cf3cf2?sk=a2307ca4fbc7b88d72e4870f69645751)

Answer (score 4):

I figured out. Hope this can help others. Never give up.

react-select v3 (v3.1.1 at this moment) doesn't have standalone lib anymore, so the only way to use it is by v2.

To use v2, you will need to include all the dependences first.

```
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.12.7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.7.2/prop-types.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/classnames@2.2.6/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-input-autosize@2.2.2/dist/react-input-autosize.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/emotion@10.0.27/dist/emotion.umd.min.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-select@2.4.4/dist/react-select.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">

const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
];

    class Hello extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return <Select options={options} />;
        }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Hello />,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, now I've recalled that I've gone this far. The amount of manually added script tags makes me thing that there's something wrong about it. +1 anyway ) What I really couldn't handle with this method is the [async plugin](https://react-select.com/async). I needed to get the list of suggestions as-you-type. And it is not packaged with unpkg.

Answer (score 0):

As of v3 (and higher) they have [deprecated the UMD builds](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/a465818786afd4857c9155bef1e9aa2fe3356097/packages/react-select/CHANGELOG.md?plain=1#L475), so you'll have to use the ESM build with `<script data-type="module">`. See here for more info: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4120#issuecomment-739138229 and an example [here](https://codepen.io/pen?template=poxZGqQ).